# create dialog appear NullPointerException in Android

Tags: java, android

This is my Model class,

```
public class VersionEntity {
    private int versionCode;
    private String path;
    private String desc;

    public int getVersionCode() {
        return versionCode;
    }
    public void setVersionCode(int versionCode) {
        this.versionCode = versionCode;
    }
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }


}
```

This is my code

```
protected void showDialog(final Message msg) {
    //LINE A
    String path = ((VersionEntity)(msg.obj)).getPath();

    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("new apk");
    builder.setMessage(((VersionEntity)(msg.obj)).getDesc());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //LINE B
//          String path = ((VersionEntity)(msg.obj)).getPath();

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancle", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(2);
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

I create a dialog when a new apk appear!

If I take LINE A and delete LINE B, it's ok!

If I take LINE B and delete LINE A, and press the button 'OK', it shows `NullPointerException`, I don't know what happened. How to fix it?

2017-01-05 add something

I change the function `protected void showDialog(final Message msg)` to `protected void showDialog(final VersionEntity ve)`,the `nullpointerexception` is disappeared,but I am still don't know why?

Comment: Please show me your logs.

Comment: Whats wrong with keeping Line A and removing Line B? You already have the variable `path`.

Comment: didn't you create your builder? i think u should have written `builder.create().show() ;`

Comment: I change the function `protected void showDialog(final Message msg)` to `protected void showDialog(final VersionEntity ve)`,the `nullpointerexception` is disappeared,but I am still don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show a `builder`. You can show a `Dialog`.

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create() ;
dialog.show() ;
```

You can have a look at the code. I think u might have a try on this. Hope this be helpful!

Comment: I had try on this,but still not use.

on my way ,the dialog is still appear

Answer (score 0):

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

                                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Title");

                                    alertDialogBuilder
                                            .setMessage("Message")
                                            .setCancelable(false)
                                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                                                    {
                                                            //Do something
                                                    }
                                            })
                                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                                            //Do something

                                                    }
                                            });

                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                                    alertDialog.show();
```